# Can't open subdirectory in File Explorer? - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I can't figure out why I can't open a subdirectory of "My Documents" in Node.js.

My current code:

```
function fileExplorer() {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child    = spawn('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe', 
    ["%userprofile%\\documents"]);
  }
```

Works completely fine to fire up the user's "My Documents" folder. However, if I want to open up a directory inside of "My Documents" like say "My Documents/Extra Stuff" the following doesn't work:

```
function fileExplorer() {
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    child    = spawn('C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe', 
    ["%userprofile%\\documents\\extra stuff"]);
  }
```

What am I missing? Forgive me if something is wrong with what I'm asking, I have a design oriented brain and am more familiar with HTML, CSS and some Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable is accessible by your code under `process.env.USERPROFILE`, so you can make this work with `path.join(process.env.USERPROFILE, 'Documents/extra stuff')`

Comment: Hey, would you mind elaborating on this? Not extremely skilled with coding and am still making my way through the learning curve.

Comment: In node.js, there are certain global variables that you can reference anywhere in your program. One of these is called `process.env`, and it holds all the environment variables that have been defined when your program starts running. If you import `var path = require('path')`, you'll get the path module which has a bunch of system path utilities. When you call `path.join(process.env.USERPROFILE, '/Documents/extra stuff')`, that takes both paths, and combines them to create a path that you can use instead of the one that isn't working.

Comment: If you try running `console.log(process.env.USERPROFILE)`, that might make things clearer

Comment: Documents not always in /user dir, **it can be moved**, but by default - it should works